# Image Background Becoming Black after converting it into URI

Tags: android, android-studio, png, uri

I require a URI file of a bitmap in my project however the bitmap is originally transparent but after I convert it into image URI the background of the age turns black, I am using this code:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, null,null));
```

How could I retain the transparency of my bitmap even while converting it into a URI?

Comment: Got this same problem but don't know how to resolve this

Comment: You could try to compress the bitmap yourself to file. And you did not tell where you got yout bitmap from.

Comment: @blackapps how could I achieve the same result?

Comment: The same? I thought you wanted something better.

Comment: I am having the same issue, getting Black Background on my image when converted to Uri, how could I avoid it? @blackapps

Comment: Read my suggestion.Try it. For the rest i dont know. And bitmaps cannot be converted to uri to begin with.

Comment: private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), inImage, "TransmissionData", null);
return Uri.parse(path);
}
I use the above code to convert my bitmap to uri, but it's having a black background
@blackapps

Comment: That is the same code as OP uses. And the bytes of byte array output stream are not used so why is it there? And you did not follow my suggestion. And one cannot convert a bitmap to an uri.

Comment: We still dont know where those bitmaps come from.

Comment: @blackapps I guess those bitmaps are generated dynamically, as in my case I use an online service to fetch the bitmap and set them as ImageView after than I convert those bitmap into Uri and then send them to Firebase Storage

Comment: I wonder what exactly you are downloading as how are the bytes of that bitmap exactly transfered? In wich format? Wasn't it a jpg file that you downloaded? And.. bitmaps cannot be converted to uries.